# How to search through multi level arrays looking for text (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to search through an array like the one below looking for pair2.php.net - what would be the most efficient way to search through the domain?  A looping foreach statement with stripos?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [host] => php.net
            [type] => MX
            [pri] => 5
            [target] => pair2.php.net
            [class] => IN
            [ttl] => 6765
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [host] => php.net
            [type] => A
            [ip] => 64.246.30.37
            [class] => IN
            [ttl] => 8125
        )

)
```

Here's my working code from the first comment's suggestion - would a different way be more efficient?

```
$search = 'secureserver.net';

$x='no!';

foreach($result AS $array1)
{
    foreach($array1 AS $array2)
    {
        if(stripos($array2,$search))
        {
            $x='yes!';
        }
    }

}  
echo $x;
```

Comment: You could use nested foreach loop.

Comment: Will it always be under the $array[$number]['target']?

Comment: No, because it won't always be in MX in the DNS as far as I know.  Searching for mail domain indicators, and I believe some will be in the A record, so I think I'll need to search all fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use a single for-loop and use the 'in_array' construct in php to look for the value in an array :-

in_array( 'pair2.php.net', $sub_array );